# Sliding doors radio button, how to enable click / checked?

Tags: jquery, css

How to enable radio button click on a button with 3 pictures?

http://jsfiddle.net/eeda6/8/

```
<div class="newsRadioButtons">
<div class="radioAll">
    <div class="radioAllLeft"></div>
    <div class="radioAllMiddle">
        <imput type="radio" checked="true" value="all" name="filter" />ALL
    </div>
    <div class="radioAllRight"></div>
</div>
<div class="radioImportant">
    <div class="radioImportantLeft"></div>
    <div class="radioImportantMiddle">
        <imput type="radio" checked="true" value="all" name="filter" />Important
    </div>
    <div class="radioImportantRight"></div>
</div>
```

​​​

Sorry for the typo error

Comment: You spelled it wrong. `imput` => `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, notice that you've written imput instead of input.
as to the solution, using jquery you can attach an event to the surrounding div so when clicking the div the input element inside of him will be checked.

```
$('.newsRadioButtons > div').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
});
```

added code example: http://jsfiddle.net/eeda6/14/

Comment: hey, quick question, what exact behavior are you trying to replicate?

Comment: I don't see you've put the javacript in there. here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/eeda6/14/

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo (`imput` instead of `input`)

http://jsfiddle.net/eeda6/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <imput type="radio" checked="true" value="all" name="filter" />
```

to

```
  <input type="radio" checked="true" value="all" name="filter" />
```